# Efficient Coding of Many Similar HTML pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, templates

I'm very new to HTML and JQuery.  I am running a website survey experiment, which means that I will have ~50 pages that are all identical with the exception of a few values.  Is there a way that I can capture the differences with a variable and loop through a template html code?  I'm already using variables in my code, but I'm not sure how or if they can be applied to instantiations of a block of HTML/JQuery code.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: create an app that uses a CMS approach or better make use of existing CMSs. Do a bit more research about that..

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET you can have a cshtml page that inherits from a layout. The layout is a single page that is always the same, while everything that inherits from it can vary slightly. More on that here: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_layout.asp

Another option is the MVC model - you can have a single page, or view, and a model which you can change dynamically. Then the view adapts to the values in your model. More on that here: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_intro.asp

All in all, what you are doing is very possible. Both of the above are good options, and there are probably more as well. Definitely don't just take the easy way out and manually create all the identical pages.